# How do you feed a tf.data.Dataset dynamically in eager execution mode where initializable_iterator isn't available?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the new approach (under eager execution) to feeding data through a dataset pipeline in a dynamic fashion, when we need to feed it sample by sample?

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` which performs some preprocessing steps and reads data from a generator, drawing from a large dataset during training.

Let's say that dataset is represented as:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ds = ds.map(tf.square).shuffle(2).batch(2)
iterator = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds)
```

After training I want to produce various visualizations which require that I feed one sample at a time through the network for inference. I've now got this dataset preprocessing pipeline that I need to feed my raw sample through to be sized and shaped appropriately for the network input.

This seems like a use case for the initializable iterator:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(placeholder)
ds = ds.map(tf.square).shuffle(2).batch(2)
iterator = tf.data.make_initializable_iterator(ds) 
# now re-initialize for each sample
```

> Keep in mind that the map operation in this example represents a long sequence of preprocessing operations that can't be duplicated for each new data sample being feed in.

**This doesn't work with eager execution**, you can't use the placeholder. The documentation examples all seem to assume a static input such as in the first example here.

The only way I can think of doing this is with a queue and `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)` which reads from the queue that I push to before predicting on the data. But this feels both hacky, and appears prone to deadlocks that I've yet to solve.

TF 1.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the answer to this question is trivial:

> Just create a new dataset!

In non-eager mode the code below would have degraded in performance because each dataset operation would have been added to the graph and never released, and in non-eager mode we have the initializable iterator to resolve that issue.

However, in eager execution mode tensorflow operations like this are ephemeral, added iterators aren't being added to a global graph, they just get created and die when no longer referenced. Win one for TF2.0!

The code below (copy/paste runnable) demonstrates:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time


tf.enable_eager_execution()

inp = np.ones(shape=5000, dtype=np.float32)

t = time.time()
while True:
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(inp).batch(1)
    val = next(iter(ds))
    assert np.all(np.squeeze(val, axis=0) == inp)
    print('Processing time {:.2f}'.format(time.time() - t))
    t = time.time()
```

The motivation for the question came on the heels of this issue in 1.14 where creating multiple dataset operations in graph mode under Keras constitutes a memory leak.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30448